# Build self contained Angular 7 library with routes and install for use in Angular 2.4.8 application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library

We are testing the ability to take a small module from our angular 2 application (angular 2.4.8, javascript, webpack, gulp, babel) and package it as a javascript library built with the angular cli using angular 7.

The idea is to have the angular 2 app play host to an angular 7 module. The site bundles/builds fine but when angular tries to load the library we get `Error: Unexpected value 'CustomModule' imported by the module 'CoreModule'↵    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor]`

CustomModule is our javascript library and Core is the angular 2 app loading it.

We were hoping that since it all compiles down to javascript in the end that angular 2 could load it and the library could be self contained.

In the end the problem is in `compiler.umd.js` with `CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata` with the method `_this.getNgModuleSummary(importedModuleType);` returning null.

Is this even possible? A quick angular 7 app spun up in the cli can host this library no problem. Is this because building an angular library strips out the metadata into its own json file?

Comment: Sounds like a valid use case for [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) to me.

Comment: @jowey it does, but doesn't that only cover components? Not a module with routing?